# Class 'Twilio\Twiml' not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twilio-twiml

```
use Twilio\Twiml;

public function welcome(Request $request)
    {
        $twiml = new Twiml();
        if(isset($request->Digits)){
            switch($request->Digits){
                case 1:
                    $twiml->say('thank you calling us');
                    break;
                default:
                    $twiml->say('You have entered wrong key');
                    break;
            }
        } else{
            $gather = $twiml->gather(array('numDigits' => 1));
            $gather->say('Thank you for calling us. Press 1 to continue the call.');
        }

        return $twiml;
    }
```

When i run this code i am getting an error that class Twlio/Twiml not found. 
For more details you can check the screenshot url(https://prnt.sc/ryz1zw) of error. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get this library? using composer? Please try to check does this library really exists in our vendor folder. Please run `composer dump-autoload` from your root directory. This error typically means that Laravel couldn't find your library using it's autoload rules.

Comment: I have get this library using composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TwiML isn’t a class, you would need to use the `VoiceResponse` to use `say()`.

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;

$response = new VoiceResponse();
$response->say('Chapeau!', ['voice' => 'woman', 'language' => 'fr-FR']);
```

[More on their docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say).

Comment: I have used the above code after then i have fixed the above issue but getting an another error twilio error 11750 TwiML response body too large

Comment: @mukesh that sounds like you’re sending something too large, or one of these: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11750